# Maps with tensors

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

I have the following map

$\pi: W \otimes V^* \rightarrow \textbf{Hom}(V,W)$

Where:

$\pi(w\otimes f)(v)= f(v)w$.

Both $V,W$ are vector spaces. And I need to prove that $\pi$ is well-defined and injective. What I'm trying to do is working with the following commutative diagram:

[image]

I have succesfully showed that $\tilde{\pi}$ is bilinear. But I am not sure if this is sufficient to say that $\pi$ is both inhective and well-defined.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is your definition of the tensor product? If you're using the universal definition (i.e. the commuting diagram definition), then $\pi$ is automatically well-defined as a consequence

Comment: Similarly, proving injectivity is easy using the universal property. Note that a linear map $\pi$ is injective if and only if there exists a "left inverse" $\sigma$, i.e. a linear map $\sigma$ such that $\sigma \circ \pi$ is the identity map.

Comment: Yes, I am using the universal definition. Then if I show the $\tilde{\pi}$ is bilinear, then $\pi$ is automatically well defined? I would also need to show that $\tilde{\pi}$ actually maps to $\textbf{Hom}(V,W)$ right?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be established that $\tilde \pi$ is a map to $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$ so that $\pi$ is a map with the same codomain.  However, it is a simple enough observation; I think it should simply be "stated" rather than "shown".

Comment: Actually, my second comment is not accurate now that I think it through.  Although the universal property is useful in showing that a map **to** a tensor product is injective, it doesn't help so much here.  Instead, use the definition of a linear map to show that if $f_1(\cdot)v_1 = f_2(\cdot)v_2$, then $f_1 \otimes v_1 = f_2 \otimes v_2$ .